# Find all subsets not included in some subsets of a set.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $\mathcal{S}^*= \{S_1, ..., S_n\}$ denote a set of subsets of a set $S$ (we have $S_i \subseteq S$).

To find all the subsets $\mathcal{C}^*= \{C_1, ..., C_m\}$ (we have $C_i \subseteq S$) such that every $C_i$ is included in every subset $S_i$ contained in $\mathcal{S}^*$, I take the intersection of these subsets:

$$I = \bigcap_{S_i \in \mathcal{S}^*} S_i$$

and then the set of subsets I am looking for  is the power set of this intersection: $\mathcal{C}^* = 2^I$.

My question is the `opposite': How to find all the subsets $\{C_1, ..., C_m\}$ such that no subset $S_i$ includes a $C_j$?  I am looking for a formula as simple as the intersection one. Is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit more complicated, but still relatively manageable. We want to start with all subsets, $2^S$, and then remove $2^{S_i}$ for each $S_i$. So we have
$$
(((2^S \setminus 2^{S_1}) \setminus 2^{S_2}) \setminus \cdots \setminus 2^{S_n}).
$$
This can be written more naturally as
$$
2^S \setminus \left(\bigcup_{i=1}^n 2^{S_i}\right).
$$